# How do I create a drill down UITable in a single view using pre-populated data from API call?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a selection method for users to pick a football team using UITableView.

When the View Controller loads I make an API call and fetch and populated the following arrays in custom structs:

`Country [name,id]
Divisions [id, country_id, name]
Teams [id, division_id, name]`

The process is:

> The user first selects a country > the ID of this country is then used to populate the table with all the divisions from that country > a division is selected which brings up all the teams in that division > a team is selected and the team name and id are passed to a variable to be used elsewhere.

At the moment the table displays all the countries.  Once a user selects a country I am using `print (self.newCountries[cellCountryId!])` to identifies and print the name of the country and it's id.

How do I now take that data and re-populate the table where `Divisions.country_id = (self.newCountries[cellCountryId!])`

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class PickTeamViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var teamsTableView: UITableView!

var pickedCountryID: Int?

var selectedCellCountryTitle: String?
var cellCountryId: Int?

struct Country {
    var name: String?
    var countryId: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.name = dictionary["name"]
        self.countryId = dictionary["id"]
    }
}


struct Divisions {
    var divisionName: String?
     var divisionId: String?
    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {

        self.divisionName = dictionary["name"]
        self.divisionId = dictionary["country_id"]
    }
}

struct Teams {
    var teamName: String?
    var newTeamId: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.teamName = dictionary["name"]

    }
}

struct TeamId {

    var newTeamId: String?

    init(_ dictionary: [String : String]) {
        self.newTeamId = dictionary["id"]

    }
}

var newCountries = [Country]()
var newDivisions = [Divisions]()
var newTeams = [Teams]()
var newTeamId = [TeamId]()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.quasisquest.uk/KeepScore/getTeams.php?");
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!);
    request.httpMethod = "GET";

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl!) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                do{
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
                    print (json)

                    if let arr = json?["countries"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newCountries = arr.flatMap { Country($0) }
                        self.teamsTableView.reloadData()

                    }


                    if let arr = json?["divisions"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newDivisions = arr.flatMap { Divisions($0) }

                    }

                    if let arr = json?["teams"] as? [[String:String]] {
                        self.newTeams = arr.flatMap { Teams($0) }

                    }


                    self.teamsTableView.reloadData()
                } catch{
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.newCountries.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let country = newCountries[indexPath.row]
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = country.name
    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cellCountryId = indexPath.row

    print (self.newCountries[cellCountryId!])

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.teamsTableView.delegate = self
     self.teamsTableView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        return
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Update your data source and reload the tableview. However, this is a terrible UI/UX design. What if the user selected the incorrect country - how do they go back to select the correct one?

Comment: You raise a good point Leo- how would you go about it in terms of UI/UX?

Comment: One way is to have a multi-stage sign up / login process, where the users goes through multiple steps, and each step is presented on a view controller of its own in a navigation stack. They can go back when needed. See for instance Apple's initial iOS setup experience. Another option is to have all the information one screen and allow the user to edit the data - for example, when tapping on a country, show a picker view. Then, the user can tap again on the country to again show the picker view.

Comment: This is after the user has logged in- and needed for if the user wants to say view stats on a particular team.  I initially was going to go with a picker but someone advised against it- though my idea was 3 pickers 'country', 'division', 'team'.  With a picker, if a user 'clicks off somewhere else' it just disappears?

Comment: I need to know more about the experience you are trying to present. One way to design a picker is in a popup or as an accessory that pops from the bottom of the screen, and can be dismissed when the user taps away.

Comment: I think the pop up method would be best- in this instance would it still disappear if the user clicked away?

Comment: Yes, you can design it like that. Look into `inputAccessoryView`.